# Reusable non generic method for generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the following base interface

```
public interface IHandler{
  void Handle(IMessage message);
}
```

and an generic interface inheriting the base interface

```
public interface IHandler<TMessage> : IHandler where TMessage : IMessage{
  void Handle(TMessage message);
}
```

My classes can implement the interface `IHandler<TMessage>` mutiple times. `IMessage` is an base interface for messages and isn´t relevant here. Currently i´m implementing the interfaces as follows.

```
public class ExampleHandler : IHandler<ExampleMessage>, IHandler<OtherExampleMessag>{

  void IHandler.Handle(IMessage message){
    ExampleMessage example = message as ExampleMessage;

    if (example != null) {
      Handle(example);
    }
    else {
      OtherExampleMessage otherExample = message as OtherExampleMessage;

      if (otherExample != null) {
        Handle(otherExample);
      }
  }

  public void Handle(ExampleMessage) {
   //handle message;
  }

  public void Handle(OtherExampleMessage) {
   //handle message;
  }
}
```

What bothers me is the way i have to implement the `Handle(IMessage)` method, cause in my opinion its many redundant code, and i have to extend the method each time when i implement a new `IHandler<TMessage>` interface on my class.

What i´m looking for is a more generic way to implement the `Handle(IMessage)` method (maybe in a base class for Handlers), but i´m currently stuck how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new `dynamic` keyword to move the overload resolution to the DLR:

```
void IHandler.Handle(IMessage message)
{
    dynamic d = message;
    Handle(d);
}
```

Please note that this will fail at runtime with a `RuntimeBinderException` if the message passed in is not valid for your class.
To avoid this exception you can add a Handler for all unknown message types:

```
private void Handle(object unknownMessage)
{
    // Handle unknown message types here.
}
```

---

To implement `IHandler.Handle` in a base class, you need to do a little bit more work:

```
public class BaseHandler : IHandler
{
    void IHandler.Handle(IMessage message)
    {
        dynamic d = message;
        Handle(d);
    }

    private void Handle<TMessage>(TMessage message) where TMessage : IMessage
    {
        var handler = this as IHandler<TMessage>;
        if(handler == null)
            HandleUnknownMessage(message);
        else
            handler.Handle(message);
    }

    protected virtual void HandleUnknownMessage(IMessage unknownMessage)
    {
        // Handle unknown message types here.
    }
}
```

Your specific handler would than look like this:

```
public class ExampleHandler : BaseHandler,
                              IHandler<ExampleMessage>,
                              IHandler<OtherExampleMessage>
{
    public void Handle(ExampleMessage message)
    {
        // handle ExampleMessage here
    }

    public void Handle(OtherExampleMessage message)
    {
        // handle OtherExampleMessage here
    }
}
```

This code now works like this:

1. The DLR calls the generic `BaseHandler.Handle<TMessage>` method with the real message type, i.e. `TMessage` will not be `IMessage` but the concrete message class like `ExampleMessage`.
2. In this geneirc handler method, the base class tries to case itself to a handler for the specific message.
3. If that is not successful, it calls `HandleUnknownMessage` to handle the unknown message type.
4. If the cast is successful, it calls the `Handle` method on the specific message handler, effectifly delegating the call to the concrete Handler implementation.

Comment: I´m not very familiar with dynamics. How does this perform compared to reflection?

Comment: Will this solution also work when i implement the `Handle(IMessage)` in a base class for my handler and derive all my handlers (implementing mutiple IHandler<T>) from this base class?

Comment: It performs better than normal reflection. It uses Reflection under the hood but applies some clever caching strategies.

Comment: @Jehof: Yes, implementing it in a base class is also possible. Please see update.

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable way would be some judicious use of reflection:

```
var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("Handle", new[] { message.GetType() });

if (method != null) {
    method.Invoke(this, new[] { message });
}
```

If you are doing this so much that performance is a problem you could cache the results of the test for a massive improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You stuck because your class (in the question) does more than one thing. It deals with `ExampleMessage` and `OtherExampleMessage`. I suggest you create one class to handle one thing.

**Example:**

```
public class ExampleHandler : IHandler<ExampleMessage>
```

and

```
public class OtherExampleHandler : IHandler<OtherExampleMessag>
```

From my understanding, you want to have a class to handle some kind of events. In this case, you may have to use [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to notify each Handler when something happen and let they do their work.

Comment: Of course i could do this, but i´m implementing my system based on CQRS and the concept of Sagas. Sagas can implement the interface multiple times to do their work and to execute other messages based on the handled message. And splitting this up to many classes isn´t useful here

Answer (score -1):

The interfaces are saying that you have an instance that provides N services. Sure the services are similar but as they are for different types they are independent services. So your detecting a 'code smell'. The smell is 'why a common method for different services?'.

So are the services different enough to justify the generic interface declarations? The fundamental here is 'duplication'. Refactor out the duplication. Duplication is **BAD**. Once you move the duplicate stuff out then the answer will be self evident.

To put this another way, get rid of the common method and handle each in its own method ... the duplication is what you want to move out to another class. If so, think injection.

Love your smell detection!

Comment: Your answer isn´t useful for me. I´m not looking for an answer about Code Smell and duplicates

Comment: Hi Jehof, I know it is not what your looking for but I do think it is a useful answer. Sorry you did not find it useful. The best answers are often not what you expect. If we restrict answers that we accept to only those we expect the that limits learning.