# Using dynamic keyword and calling generic method in base class results in StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dynamic, .net-4.0

According to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855930/reusable-non-generic-method-for-generic-methods) (Reusable non generic method for generic methods) i have implemented the provided solution, but after some refactoring (moving code to base class) my code results in a StackOverflowException that i don´t understand.

The call to `Handle(new TestCommand())` results in that `IMessageHandler.Handle(IMessage)` gets called and then `Handle<TMessage>(TMessage)` gets called, but instead of calling `Handle(TestCommand message)` of the inherited class it calls `IMessageHandler.Handle(IMessage)` again.

The as-cast to `IMessageHandler<TestCommand>` in the generic method works, otherwise it would call `HandleUnknownMessage(IMessage)`.

Its hard to describe so instead here´s my TestCode:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        MyProcess p = new MyProcess();
        IMessageHandler handler = p;

        handler.Handle(new DummyCommand()); // works -> HandleUnknownMessage gets called as expected

        handler.Handle(new TestCommand());  // fails -> results in a StackOverflowException 
    }
}  

public abstract class ProcessBase : IMessageHandler {
    void IMessageHandler.Handle(IMessage message) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Dynamic Message gets handled");
        dynamic dynamicMessage = message;

        Handle(dynamicMessage);
    }

    private void Handle<TMessage>(TMessage message) where TMessage : IMessage {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Generic Message gets handled");
        var handler = this as IMessageHandler<TMessage>;
        if (handler == null)
            HandleUnknownMessage(message);
        else
            handler.Handle(message);
    }

    protected virtual void HandleUnknownMessage(IMessage unknownMessage) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unknown message {0} passed to Process".FormatWith(unknownMessage.GetType()));
        // Handle unknown message types here.
    }
}

public class MyProcess : ProcessBase, IMessageHandler<TestCommand>, IMessageHandler<TestEvent> {

    public void Handle(TestCommand commandMessage) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TestCommand gets handled");
    }

    public void Handle(TestEvent eventMessage) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TestEvent gets handled");
    }
}

public class DummyCommand : IMessage {    }

public class TestCommand : IMessage {    }
```

If i put the code from my base class `ProcessBase` to `MyProcess`, the code works without problem. Are there any limitations in use of the dynamic keyword in conjuction with generic methods and inheritance?

Comment: Does `IMessageHandler<T>` define a `Handle<T>(T)` method? EDIT: Can you post `IMessageHandler` and `IMessageHandler<T>`?

Comment: @Chris Sinclair: Damn, you are right. I have missed to define the Handle<T> on IMessageHandler<T>.

Comment: No problem. I'm going to have to remember this technique; it's a clever way of promoting a run-time call into a compile-time generic call. (I would suggest renaming the private `Handle<TMessage>` method on `ProcessBase` just to avoid hairyness on the method resolution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining on `IMessageHandler<TMessage>` a `void Handle<TMessage>(TMessage message)` method.

Since it's not defined, your `MyProcess.Handle` events that you've defined belong *only* to that class and not to the interfaces it implements. When your code attempts to call on your `IMessageHandler<TMessage> handler`, it doesn't know that it's actually a `MyProcess` that has those specific methods. Once you add the interface method, the call resolution should recognize that those methods exist on `MyProcess` and call them. Otherwise it just calls the next best method being `IMessageHandler.Handle(IMessage)` which produces an infinite loop.